# Detect visual attention area in an image

Tags: machine-learning, algorithms, image-processing, computer-vision, object-detection

I'm trying to detect the visual attention area in a given image and crop the image into that area. For instance, given an image of any size and a rectangle of say LxW dimension as an input, I would like to crop the image to the most important visual attention area. I'm looking for a state of the art approach for that.

Do we have any tools or SDK to implement that? Any piece of code or algorithm would really help.

Answer (score 1):

I would go about it by picking a state-of-the-art object detector (e.g., YOLO, https://pjreddie.com/darknet/yolo/) and run it over a given image. Then, I would take the min and max values of the bounding boxes in x & y direction, and based on these 4 coordinates, you can then crop the image in such a way that it contains all objects that were detected (and thereby, you supposedly get rid of rather unimportant content).

Comment: This is good, thanks, but within a "single" object, I would like to get attention.

Comment: btw, how to get the bounding boxes? I don't see those info in the output!

Comment: Maybe see the solution to a similar question posted on stack overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44544471/how-to-get-the-coordinates-of-the-bounding-box-in-yolo-object-detection